# automatic way for determining ARIMA(p,d,q) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, forecasting, moving-average, autoregressive-models

I would like to ask you if there is any automated method for calculating the order of `ARIMA(p,d,q)` model for any type of a time series data, in MATLAB.

This will make the forecasting model more accurate and will also save me some time. I would appreciate if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for, but maybe this post on Matlab File Exchange?

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25611-arfima-simulations